# Remove seconds from toLocaleTimeString

Tags: javascript, regex, date

The `Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()` method returns a string with a language sensitive representation of the time portion of this date. It is available for modern browsers.

Unfortunately, the native function **is not able** to prevent the **output of seconds**. By default, it outputs a time format like `hh:mm:ss` or `hh:mm AM/PM` etc.

> **second**: The representation of the second. Possible values are "`numeric`", "`2-digit`".

Source: [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)

This means, that you can not use something like `{second: false}`.

---

I'm looking for a *simple stupid* solution, to **remove the seconds** from a `hh:mm:ss` formatted string.

```
var date = new Date();
var time = date.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
console.log(time); // 15:24:07
```

This regular expressions **don't** work:

```
time.replace(/:\d\d( |$)/,'');
time.replace(/(\d{2}:\d{2})(?::\d{2})?(?:am|pm)?/);
```

Comment: @Halcyon Thank you, but this does not work http://jsfiddle.net/e73GY/

Comment: `time = time.substr(0,5);` doofus :P

Comment: Similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913681/how-do-i-use-tolocaletimestring-without-displaying-seconds

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use:

```
var time = date.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'})
           .replace(/(:\d{2}| [AP]M)$/, "");
```

btw `Google Chrome` returns

```
new Date().toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
```

as `"12:40 PM"`

Comment: Yes, `hh:mm:ss` is the default output format. I have enabled the 24h time display format on my system.

Comment: ok adding `.replace(/(:\d{2}| [AP]M)$/, "");` would work in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another possible combination to achieve this:

```
(new Date()).toLocaleTimeString().match(/\d{2}:\d{2}|[AMP]+/g).join(' ')
```

Comment: Thank you, but this removes the time completely, when the system format output is set to `hh:mm AM/PM`.

Comment: It actually works with your format `hh:mm:ss` AM or PM is optional in the expression