# i want to use date function in javascript to get date as Sunday, September 8 at 11:46am

Tags: javascript

i want to use date function in javascript  to get date as  Sunday, September 8 at 11:46am

below is the code i am using -:
`var currentTime = new Date()`

```
var dd1 = currentTime.getDate();
var mm1 = currentTime.getMonth()+1; // January is 0!
var yyyy1 = currentTime.getFullYear();

if(dd1 < 10)
{
    dd1 = '0'+ dd1;
}
if(mm1 < 10)
{
    mm1 = '0' + mm1;
}
var date = dd1 + '/' + mm1 + '/' + yyyy1;
```

but this gives out put as -: 08/09/2013 instead i want to get it as -: Sunday, September 8 at 11:46am

Comment: Try google to meet your needs.. i found this from it.
http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/rYzAY/

Comment: -1 : just read the specifications of the Date Object == google "mdn date" for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sample code will be helpful:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<script>

    var current_date = new Date ( );
    var month_names = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var day_names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

    var hours = current_date.getHours();
    var minutes = current_date.getMinutes();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;

    // Display date in required format
    var formatted_date = day_names[current_date.getDay()] + ", " + month_names[current_date.getMonth()] + " " + current_date.getDate() + " at " + " " + hours + ":" + minutes +  ampm ;
    console.log( formatted_date );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Resources:

[Working with date formatting in javascript](http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/)

[Display javascript datetime in 12 hour AM/PM format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format)

Comment: the algorithm looks correct (good job), but please first let someone review your code. This is a bad way to create an array of constants (see [7's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18681183/499214)), and `document.write` is downright bad (I doubt the asker is doing it during the initial page load, and even then DOM manipulation works just as fine and is more flexible). You can use `console.log` to demonstrate the usage of some variable instead - note that you'll have to concatenate it first.

Comment: Yes you are right about the way code is written, but I have just shown a way. I know this is not an optimal solution. It is just a way of formatting the date in pure JavaScript.

Comment: You should fix the code to use good coding practices (use an array literal and remove `document.write`), then I'll upvote.

Comment: If you don't, would you mind if I fix that for you when I get home? I don't want to shoot down an answer that would otherwise be useful just for the bad coding style it promotes.

Comment: thanks alot friends and special thanks to Sameer Mahant the script provided by u works and gives the output as i need. thanks alot

Comment: @user1659298 don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem. I've edited in another small fix, though.

Comment: thanks Jan Dvorak .... will keep this in mind from next time....accepted the solution provided by sameer

Answer (score 1):

Try,

`var date = new Date( dd1 + '/' + mm1 + '/' + yyyy1);`

instead

```
 var date = dd1 + '/' + mm1 + '/' + yyyy1;
```

**Little messy**

```
var date = new Date  ( dd1 + '/' + mm1 + '/' + yyyy1);
var name = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][date.getDay()];
var monthName = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ][date.getMonth()];
alert (name + " , "  + monthName + " " + date.getDate()+ " at " + "  your time as you like");
```

Comment: Uh... no, that won't produce the required format (though it might be good enough for the asker's needs)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a good JavaScript date formatting library. Try [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)
You will have to read their formatting docs to figure out how to do what you need - but you can do it

Comment: At 15k you should know the stance on link-only answers. Code samples, please?

Comment: at 12k you should know that i am not required to hand the OP code on silver platter

Comment: It is link-only. It is also technically incorrect (it can well be done without a library), but that's beside the point. You don't have to hand the OP code, but just pointing to a library is not useful. At the very least, you could quote the relevant documentation here. Even pointing to the documentation would be more helpful than this.

Comment: fair enough, but its its 2:30am down here and this is the best i can do. no one else seems to know any better

Comment: Also note the tag wiki states "Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.".

Comment: note that you serve as an example for newbie answerers. You _should_ give a good example (even if only in the morning - please ping me then so I can upvote)

Comment: I don't have the time now, but I can post a no-library answer in a few hours when I return.

Comment: you didnt post it, its been a few years!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `toDateString` function would help

```
var objDate = new Date();
var strDate = objDate.toDateString();
var intHrs = objDate.getHours();
var intMin = objDate.getMinutes();

alert(strDate + ' ' + intHrs + ' : ' + intMins);
```

Complete reference on Date object from MDN available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirect=no)

Comment: Uh... no, that won't produce the required format. Namely, the time is not present (though it might be close enough for asker's need after the time string is appended)

Comment: Updated to display time

Comment: it still displays "Sun Sep" instead of "Sunday, "September"

Comment: Yup. Stuck with that.