# Javascript document.lastModified is returning current date and time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm  using the standard `document.lastModified` Javascript property to output the supposed last modified date of the page, but it's outputting the actual current date and time. Any clue as to why it'd behave this way as opposed to outputting the actual last modified property of the page? This happens both locally (on my machine) as well as the published page on the delivery server.

Comment: The standard what now? That is DOM Level 0, and not standardized anywhere ?

Comment: 'Gets the date that the document was last modified, if the document supplies one.' Check the HTTP headers.

Comment: `lastModified` is a value in the response headers. Are you dynamically creating this resource on your server?

Comment: i believe document.lastModified is simply the same time as the lastModified header, if it was sent, or the current time if the server omitted that header..

Comment: @adeno - the standard Javascript attribute "lastModified" of the document object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*document.lastModified* I imagine is based on the HTTP Response Header field [Last-Modified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses) ([RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822)). Last-Modified is usually used in conjunction with the Request header field If-Modified-Since for caching purposes.

Like other header fields, it's server implementation specific as to what value is returned. The server software replying to your HTTP Request might or might not return the Last-Modified header field in the HTTP Response.

In the pages you are running this on, the server simply returns the current date. Same is true for this page.

However execute *document.lastModified* (in Dev Tools) on say https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.lastModified, you'll get **11/13/2013 09:13:29**

Using firebug in Firefox or Chrome Dev Tools in Chrome, you can see inspect HTTP traffic data in the [Network](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network-files/headers.png) tab.

Comment: I think this may be the issue — thanks for the information @cbayram.

Comment: So, what's the solution for this?? How can I change the behaviour of the server software???

Answer (score 0):

Tested lastModified on a local file on my hard drive.
Chrome returns current time/date and not when file was saved.
Internet Explorer and Firefox return time/date file was saved.
So this is a Chrome bug.
Get page to check if Chrome from the userAgent and warn user or disable code.

> > Blockquote
>
> if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome/")>0){   alert("Chrome
>   bug.\nPlease use a different browser.\nOne that works."); }
>
> > Blockquote

Other problems with lastModified.
It returns a string and not a date object. So can't use date.getFullYear()
The string is in the USA format and not the standard format of d/mm/yyyy