# Using a 12 hour format

Tags: javascript, date, time

http://jsfiddle.net/2Tcvc/

```
document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = formatAMPM();

function formatAMPM() {
    var d = new Date(),
        minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getMinutes() :         d.getMinutes(),
        hours = d.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '' + d.getHours() : d.getHours(), 
        ampm = d.getHours() >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am',
        months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',     'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    return days[d.getDay()] + ', ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getDate() + ', ' + d.getFullYear() + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ampm;
}
```

I'm not very good with js and everytime I try something it breaks. 
Can anyone show me how to show a 12hr format and possibly explain what's happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When the hour is greater than 12 you have to substract 12. And when it's equal to 0, change it to 12.

Comment: Also check if maybe `toLocaleString();` would be ok for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract 12 from the hours if it's PM, and change 0 to 12am.

```
hours = d.getHours();
ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
if (hours == 0) {
    hours = 12; // midnight is 12am
} else if (hours > 12) {
    hours -= 12;
}
if (hours.toString().length == 1) {
    hours = '0' + hours;
}
```