# separate Date and time with AM or PM?

Tags: javascript

I have  8/28/2014 12:00:00 AM and i want to access Date= 8/12/2014 and time= 12:00 AM.
How can i separate this date and time in javascript?
I used the following code and got the date according to my requirement but i got time 0:00 but i need 12:00 AM.How it is possible?

```
 var date = new Date(starttime);
 var startday = date.getDate();
 var startmonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
 var startyear = date.getFullYear();
 var formatDate = startday + "/" + startmonth + "/" + startyear;
 var starttime = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();
```

Comment: how can i access the AM or PM of Time?

Comment: see my answer it does exactly what you asked for.. and dont forget to mark it as correct (:

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it:

```
selectedDateTime = "2009-08-12 14:30:00 AM"   //This is what you currently have
var splitarray = new Array();
splitarray= selectedDateTime.split(" ");

var date = splitarray[0];
var time = splitarray[1] + splitarray[2];

alert("Date: "+ date + "  Time: " + time)
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/86nrp0s6/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  SimpleDateFormat Date_Time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a / MMM dd EEE");
  SimpleDateFormat Date_Time = new SimpleDateFormat(temp_date_time);
  String Date_Time_dip = Date_Time.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Hours = date.getHours();
var Mins = date.getMinutes();
var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
hours = hours % 12;
hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
```

Source: [How do you display javascript datetime in 12 hour AM/PM format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine.

The only thing is;
AM vs PM:
Each period consists of 12 hours numbered: 12 (acting as zero for AM),

AM-> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
PM-> 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23

You should write date as "8/28/2014 12:00:00 PM", not "8/28/2014 12:00:00 AM". Because 12 is PM, not AM, if you mean noon.

If you write 12:00:00 AM, javascript will understand it as 24:00 or 00:00. 12 is midnight for AM.