# How to convert this to show 12 hour clock?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently shows the time in a 24 Hour clock format. Can this be chnaged to show a 12 Hour clock with AM or PM? Thanks

```
function startTime() {
  var today=new Date();
  var h=today.getHours();
  var m=today.getMinutes();
  var s=today.getSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h+":"+m+":"+s;
  var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}
```

Comment: just a quick answer but: `if(var h > 12){var time = am; h = h / 2 }`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format

Comment: Answer to your question: yes it can.  My question to you: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to continue formatting manually, you can use something like this:

```
element.innerHTML = (h > 12 ? h - 12 : h) + ":" + m + ":" + s + (h >= 12 ? " PM" : " AM");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date().toLocaleTimeString()

/*  returned value: (String)
```

eg. 11:25:50 AM

or 8:08:41 PM
    */

Answer (score 0):

```
function startTime() {
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        m = checkTime(m);
        s = checkTime(s);
        var ampm = h >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
        h = h % 12;
        h = h ? h : 12;
        m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;
        var strTime = h + ':' + m + ':' + s +' ' + ampm;
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = strTime;
        var t = setTimeout(function () { startTime() }, 500);
    }

    function checkTime(i) {
        if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i };  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
        return i;
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1k6f5vx0/)**