# javascript string to time and am/pm format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a time in string format

```
var start = "14:00:00"
```

and I need the output to be

`02:00pm`

```
<span>{{session.start | some-format}} to {{session.end}}<span>
```

or javascript manipulation (any will do)

I looked up this page but it needs some kind of time stamp I guess.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format maybe?

Comment: the input is date, but here i've a string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do something like:

```
function toTime(timeString){
    var timeTokens = timeString.split(':');
    return new Date(1970,0,1, timeTokens[0], timeTokens[1], timeTokens[2]);
}

var start = "14:00:00";
var date = toTime(start);

then apply the angular filter:

<span>{{date | date:'h:mm a'}} to {{session.end}}<span>
```

Comment: just a little more help please, how could I use the date constructor with your solution above `new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, millisecond]]]]]);` to make my code less verbose, as I've to do the same for session.end

Comment: how about this `var tokens = sessions[i].start.split(":");
            sessions[i].start = new Date(null, null, null, tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2]);`

Answer (score 3):

Using [moment](http://momentjs.com/) you can do something like this:

```
var timeArr = "14:00:00".split(':');

var date = new Date().setHours(timeArr[0], timeArr[1], timeArr[2])

var startTime = moment(date).format("h:mm:ss A");

var endTime = moment().format("h:mm:ss A");
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw you mentioned angular documentation in the question so if you are after an Angular approach you can give it a try with this:

```
$scope.start = new Date();
{{ start | date: 'shortTime'}}
```

Example here:
[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YC29SdASNXtH5DexQ0x6?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function timeConvert (time) {
  time = time.toString ().match (/^([01]\d|2[0-3])(:)([0-5]\d)(:[0-5]\d)?$/) || [time];

  if (time.length > 1) { 
    time = time.slice (1);  
    time[5] = +time[0] < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
    time[0] = +time[0] % 12 || 12;
  }
  return time.join ('');
}

timeConvert ('19:00:00');
```

out: "7:00:00PM"