# how to store user entered time in mysql in AM/PM

Tags: mysql, angularjs

I need to store time which is in the form of HH: MM AM/PM which is entered from angular js front end.

HTML

```
<input type="time" ng-model="booktime">
```

Controller

```
$http.post("url", { 
    'booktime':booktime,
    .then(function(response) {
    },function(error) {
        alert("");
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Mysql

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(booktime)
VALUES (TIME_FORMAT( '11:00:00', '%h:%i:%s %p' ))";
```

Comment: Do not store am / pm, format the time in the application when you retrieve it.

Comment: MySQL DATETIME and TIME datatypes only support 24 clock you need the application to handle the am / pm..

Comment: Please provide some examples

Comment: @user3698911 you have already found a way, it is in your question. Just use it in a select...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript string to time and am/pm format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835299/javascript-string-to-time-and-am-pm-format)

Answer (score -1):

You SHOULD NOT insert datetime in any other format than `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

If you want to show to user formatted time, then do it whilst/after retrieving it from a database. For example in `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(booktime, '%h:%i:%s %p') AS booktime FROM table
```

or in your view.