# javascript formatting time from Date() object

Tags: javascript, datetime

1.) Is there a built in formatting option in javascript to display time obtained from Date() to be 12 hr format?

2.) With the script below the minutes and seconds field are displayed as 1 digit format when the values are less than 10. Is there a way force 2 digit reporting on the minutes/seconds values so that 1.. 2... 3...  displays as  01... 02... 03... and so on....

```
function updateTime(){
    var dt = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0]=  'Sunday';
weekday[1] = 'Monday';
weekday[2] = 'Tuesday';
weekday[3] = 'Wednesday';
weekday[4] = 'Thursday';
weekday[5] = 'Friday';
weekday[6] = 'Saturday';
    var time = weekday[dt.getDay()] + ' ' + dt.getDate() + '/' + dt.getMonth() + '/' + dt.getFullYear() + ' ' +dt.getHours() + ':' + dt.getMinutes() + ':' + dt.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById('dttime').innerHTML = time;
}
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your life simple.
Use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
function updateTime(){
  var time = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
  document.getElementById('dttime').innerHTML = time;
}
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bt7vkra/1/)

Comment: Although my own answer worked just fine, your answer is much cleaner and moment.js is compact enough to not impact processing/load time. So im good with accepting yours, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1) Sort of. Simply do `""+dt` and you'll get the date formatted according to the browser's locale. In theory at least, if your computer is set to 12-hour, then the result will be too.

2) You can zero-pad with `("0"+dt.getHours()).slice(-2)`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I did miss a built in function, here is what I ended up with that works as needed.

```
function updateTime(){
    var dt = new Date();
    var n = dt.toLocaleTimeString(); <-- added new var converts dt to local time string
    var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0]=  'Sunday';
weekday[1] = 'Monday';
weekday[2] = 'Tuesday';
weekday[3] = 'Wednesday';
weekday[4] = 'Thursday';
weekday[5] = 'Friday';
weekday[6] = 'Saturday';
    var time = weekday[dt.getDay()] + ' ' + dt.getDate() + '/' + dt.getMonth() + '/' + dt.getFullYear() + ' ' + n;  <-- removed getMin/GetSec and replaced with N variable.
    document.getElementById('dttime').innerHTML = time;
}
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```