# How to convert the time from ''hh:mm:ss' format to an 'Hourly' format using jquery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a label showing the current time: I used to get the current time in 'hh:mm:ss':

```
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
```

o/p: `Data current as of 14:20:35`

now how can i convert this time into an hourly format: `Data current as of 2:30pm-PST`
( assuming the current time is 2:30pm)?
Any ideas?? 
Thanks!

Comment: Uhm, if I understand your question, wouldn't that just be `var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();` for yoou?

Comment: PS: You don't have to favourite each of your own questions; you can find them back in the Questions tab on your profile: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4021059/user1234?tab=questions

Comment: Do you want to achieve something like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format

Comment: @BaliBalo: thanks, yes looking something similar to that! is there any way to get the timezone as well???Eg: 4:00pm PST?

Comment: found the answer: function getTimeZone() {
    return /\((.*)\)/.exec(new Date().toString())[1];
}

getTimeZone();