# HTML. Set datetime-local AM/PM automatically on page load

Tags: javascript, html

How do i set a datetime-local value to mm/dd/yyyy --:-- AM/PM automatically? I don't know how to start and i've been search since yesterday on how to do it.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use momentjs(http://momentjs.com/) for date formatting

```
moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A');
```

Answer (score 2):

Visit this link for reference http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp 
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Get a local time using:

```
var now = new Date();
```

convert local time into UTC format:

```
var UTCFormat = now.toUTCString();
```

you can go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) to read more about conversions.