# How to pass dynamic values as objects inside data in line chart?

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am using line chart to display the values of time in x-axis and speed of vehicle in y-axis and these both values needs to be come from api. As of now i am using static values like,

playback.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-play-back',
  templateUrl: './play-back.component.html'
})
export class PlayBackComponent {
  // lineChart
  public lineChartData:Array<any> = [
    {data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55], label: 'travelled details'}
  ];
  public lineChartLabels:Array<any> = ['12:00 AM', '4:00 AM', '8:00 AM', '12:00 PM', '4:00 PM', '8:00 PM'];
  public lineChartOptions:any = {
    responsive: true
  };
  public lineChartLegend:boolean = true;
  public lineChartType:string = 'line'; 
}
```

Instead of this static values in data and label, i have to pass the dynamic values from api which is in the form of objects. Those values are stored in chart details as in the image,

[image]

I am passing integer as data values now in static but actually i need to pass the object from api inside the data, from the chart details object fixTime values in x-axis and speed value in y-axis. Kindly help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [formatAMPM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888498/6100785) as a helper, you can make something like:

```
data = objects.map(item => { return item.speed; })
labels = objects.map(item => { return formatAMPM(item.fixTime); })
```