# How to display Date and Time 12 hour format Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, datetime

This is an answer for How to display Date and Time 12-hour format Using Jquery, I was searching for an answer but my searching hasn't given me simple solution on the internet. I wrote my own solution and here it is.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var dd = d.getDate();
  var yy = d.getFullYear();
  var t = d.toLocaleString([], {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit'
  });
  var dt = (mm < 10 ? '0' : '') + mm + '/' + (dd < 10 ? '0' : '') + dd + '/' + yy + " - " + t;
  $('#date').html(dt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='date'></p>
```

Comment: Even if does not provide an answer to your question, i recommend you to take a look to `momentjs` library for manipulate, format, ... dates in JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you display JavaScript datetime in 12 hour AM/PM format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format)

Comment: I've removed a couple of tags (your question does not seem related to neither Microsoft Windows APIs nor jQuery). Feel free to correct me if I overlooked something.

Comment: You don't really need jQuery for this.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ: Thanks for the suggestion definitely, I will look into it.

Comment: @Álvaro González: Not really, but thanks for sharing the solution I didn't find that when I was looking for and No problem removing the tags.

Comment: @Dionei Miodutzki: what do you recommend...? I want to use in MVC5 .vbhtml Razor engine....?

Answer (score 0):

You should use below code,

```
new Date($.now());
```

Comment: Use substring to cut and display the portion you want

Comment: I tried above code but it resulted in General date/time pattern (long time). Which i don't want my output should be 03/30/2018 - 09:38 AM

Comment: You can substring and arrange as per your requirement. Now() will give you all information. Which you can use to form any kind of date formate.