# How To Get Time And Date Format In 12 Hour?

Tags: javascript, ajax, datetime-format

I Want Date and Time In 12 Hour Format.

```
function view_users(id)
{
  var td = data.CreatedOn;
  var dateTime = new Date(td*1000);
  var Created = dateTime.toString();           
  $('#CreatedOn').text(Created);
}
```

Right Now i am getting Following OutPut.

```
Created:Fri Jan 11 2019 09:21:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: Please give an example of the expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you display JavaScript datetime in 12 hour AM/PM format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can Try this**

```
 function format_time(date_obj) {
      // formats a javascript Date object into a 12h AM/PM time string
      var hour = date_obj.getHours();
      var minute = date_obj.getMinutes();
      var amPM = (hour > 11) ? "pm" : "am";
      if(hour > 12) {
        hour -= 12;
      } else if(hour == 0) {
        hour = "12";
      }
      if(minute < 10) {
        minute = "0" + minute;
      }
      return hour + ":" + minute + amPM;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many way to convert time.
I want to try to answer with my way :

```js
var now = new Date();
var year = now.getFullYear();
var month = now.getMonth()+1;
var date = now.getDate();
var hours = now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes();
var second = now.getSeconds();
var times ='';

if(hours>12){
  times = '0'+hours%12 +':'+minutes+':'+second+' PM'
}
else{
  times = '0'+hours%12 +':'+minutes+':'+second+' AM'
}

console.log(year+'-'+month+'-'+date+' '+times);
```

You can use another way, and pardon me if this is not best answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need much date formatting, and don't need to support anything below IE11, the following minimal example should work.

```js
const date = new Date();

console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

You may need to input the options as well if it does not work to your liking like so:

`date.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour12: true })`

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString