# i want to display AM / PM using javascript

Tags: javascript

i try to disply time with the showing AM / PM format but i am unable to find any code can you please guide me

```js
var dt = new Date();

var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
document.getElementById("dt").innerHTML = time;
```

```html
<p id='dt'></p>
```

Comment: Try `new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US')`

Comment: Try out this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds()+"  ";
time+= dt.getHours()>=12?"PM":"AM"
document.getElementById("dt").innerHTML = time;
```

```html
<div id="dt"></div>
```

Comment: It won't work afternoon...

Comment: `12:01` is a PM.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the hours to if its less than 12 and if so set a variable to either AM or PM. Note that the following has the leading 0 added to the mins and secs if required (the slice will only include the 0 if the length of the value is 1).

```js
var dt = new Date();
var hrs = dt.getHours();
var hours = hrs % 12;



var mins = '0' + dt.getMinutes();
var minutes = mins.slice(-2);

var secs = '0' + dt.getSeconds();
var seconds = secs.slice(-2);

var amPm = hrs< 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';

var time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ' ' +  amPm; 


document.getElementById("dt").innerHTML = time;
```

```html
<p id = "dt"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the value less than 12, and keep the hours under 12 and return 12 instead of 0 by: `(hours %12 || 12)`:

```
var dt = new Date();

var time = (dt.getHours()%12||12) + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds() + " " + (dt.getHours() < 12)===0?"AM" : "PM";
document.getElementById("dt").innerHTML = time;
```