# Display time as AM, PM in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am beginner in java script i tried to show time as "AM" & "PM" using if else condition. It works but the problem is at time of 12 am or 12 pm it always show "0 am" and "0 pm". Can any one tell me where i am doing mistake. my code is

```
const today = new Date();
const day = today.getDay();
const dayList = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = `Today is : ${dayList[day]}.`;

let hour = today.getHours();

const minute = today.getMinutes();
const second = today.getSeconds();

let prepand = (hour >= 12) ? " PM " : " AM ";

hour = (hour >= 12) ? hour - 12 : hour;

if (hour === 12 && prepand === ` PM` && minute === 0 && second === 0) {
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = `Current Time is : ${hour}${prepand} : ${minute} : ${second}`;
} else {
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = `Current Time is : ${hour}${prepand} : ${minute} : ${second}`;
}
```

Comment: The code inside the two branches of the `if` statement is exactly the same, why do you think it should behave differently?

Comment: You should use [`Date#toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) instead.

Comment: toLocaleTimeString() may behave differently based on region / location.

Answer (score 0):

You are kind of over complicating this. Javascript has a way to get the long day name and 12 hour format natiely.

```js
// just to update the time
window.setInterval(function() {

  let d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = `Today is : ${d.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {weekday: 'long'})}.`;
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = `Current Time is : ${d.toLocaleString('en-GB', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: true })} : ${d.getMinutes()} : ${d.getSeconds()}`;

}, 1000); // every second
```

```html
<p id=date></p>
<p id=time></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there are simpler ways to do this, and [the problem is not a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format).

However in the interests of learning, of course you want to know what is wrong with your own code, so let's solve it!  The issue is this line:

```
hour = (hour >= 12) ? hour - 12 : hour;
```

If the time is 12 (am or pm), this sets hour to 0.  The fix is simple, subtract 12 only when `hour` is *greater* than 12:

```
hour = (hour > 12) ? hour - 12 : hour;
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/1erh2gun/) (hardcodes hour to 12 to test).

Comment: @Fraser Thank you for suggesting me a new solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot you actually got my point that i wanted to catch my mistake which i did in this code.