# javascript date format yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, date-format, date-parsing

I have facing an issue in javascript date format all dates in this format `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss`

My Code:

```
var currentdate = new Date();
var prevdate = new Date();
var firstdate = new Date();

prevdate.setTime(currentdate.getTime() - (30 * 60 * 1000));
firstdate.setTime(currentdate.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));

var current = currentdate.toLocaleTimeString(); 
var previous = prevdate.toLocaleTimeString();      
var first = firstdate.toLocaleTimeString();
```

console data

```
console.log(previous);   //10:28:24 PM
console.log(current);    //10:58:24 PM
console.log(first);      //11:28:24 PM
```

I try this , how can i pass `previous` and `first` date

```
var Currentdate=dateFormat(new Date(), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss");
console.log("Currentdate");  //2020-05-07 22:58:11
```

Expected Output Date Format: `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss`

```
previous date: 2020-05-07 22:28:11   // date before 30min
current date:  2020-05-07 22:58:11   // current date 
first date:    2020-05-07 23:28:11   // date after 30min
```

What should i do? can anyone help?

Comment: Why did you think a Locale**Time**String would include the date?

Comment: i don't show date with `AM` or `PM` i.e LocaleTimeString  i use [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: sorry i don;t understand your point [@jonsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)

Comment: I was surprised how hard it was to find this approach: `const timeZone = 'America/New_York';
const dateString = new Date(someDate).toLocaleString('se-SE', { timeZone });
console.log({ dateString });`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `currentdate.toLocaleString()` instead, as `toLocaleTimeString()` 
 returns a string with a language sensitive representation of the time portion of this date

[toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

[toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)

Answer (score 0):

Use `toLocaleString` instead of `toLocaleTimeString`

Comment: i  want to show date with`LocaleTimeString`  with `AM` and `PM`  [@mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4186110/mark-partola)

Comment: It can be useful for that
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888498/4186110

Comment: Try using options `toLocaleString('en-US', { hour12: true })`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `toLocaleString`

```js
var currentdate = new Date();
var prevdate = new Date();
var firstdate = new Date();

prevdate.setTime(currentdate.getTime() - (30 * 60 * 1000));
firstdate.setTime(currentdate.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));

var options = { hour12: false };

var current = currentdate.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
var previous = prevdate.toLocaleString('en-US', options);      
var first = firstdate.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
current = current.replace(/\//g, '-');
previous = previous.replace(/\//g, '-');
first = first.replace(/\//g, '-');

console.log(`current: ${current}`);
console.log(`previous: ${previous}`);
console.log(`first: ${first}`);
```

Comment: thanks but how can i remove the `/` from dates instead of  `-` format `5-7-2020, 23:42:18` [@Sifat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5146848/sifat-haque)

Comment: Please check now. I've updated my answer. Please make it as correct answer if it helps. @adnankhan

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try th following function:

```
function getTime(){
    var date = new Date();
    console.log(GetFormattedDate(date));
}



function GetFormattedDate(date) {
    var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var day  = ("0" + (date.getDate())).slice(-2);
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var hour =  ("0" + (date.getHours())).slice(-2);
    var min =  ("0" + (date.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
    var seg = ("0" + (date.getSeconds())).slice(-2);
    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" +  min + ":" + seg;
}
```

in your case

```
function getTime(){
    var date = new Date();

    var currentdate = new Date();
    var prevdate = new Date();
    var firstdate = new Date();

    prevdate.setTime(currentdate.getTime() - (30 * 60 * 1000));
    firstdate.setTime(currentdate.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));


    console.log(GetFormattedDate(prevdate));
    console.log(GetFormattedDate(currentdate));
    console.log(GetFormattedDate(firstdate));
}



function GetFormattedDate(date) {
    var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var day  = ("0" + (date.getDate())).slice(-2);
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var hour =  ("0" + (date.getHours())).slice(-2);
    var min =  ("0" + (date.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
    var seg = ("0" + (date.getSeconds())).slice(-2);
    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" +  min + ":" + seg;
}
```

regards

Comment: they show `current date` how can i pass `previous data` and `first date` please? [@cristopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12053529/cristopher-fuentealba)

Comment: hi, i edited the response with your case
regards

Comment: ok i try this [@Cristopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12053529/cristopher-fuentealba)

Comment: one more thing i ask, how should i get value from `console.log(GetFormattedDate(prevdate))` outside the `getTime` function [@Cristopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12053529/cristopher-fuentealba)

Comment: it's not necessary use the function getTime(), you can call GetFormattedDate() as long as you pass date  variable or  as also assign to the new variable

Comment: i can't get the `console.log` value outside the `getTime` function, can u help me? [@cristopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12053529/cristopher-fuentealba)

Comment: i want to pass these `dates` values in `if else` condition, how i pass or call ? `console.log(GetFormattedDate(prevdate))` [@cristopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12053529/cristopher-fuentealba)

Comment: i  print `console.log(GetFormattedDate(prevdate))` outside the `getTime` function it show `undefined` [@cristopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12053529/cristopher-fuentealba)

Comment: should i return the `dates` values? `getTime()` function? (@cristopher)[https://stackoverflow.com/users/12053529/cristopher-fuentealba]

Comment: the var prevdate is not declare out of the getTime function, you should declare prevdate  amd modify time and call GetFormattedDate(prevdate)

Comment: ok i got thanks [@cristopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12053529/cristopher-fuentealba)