# How to format user input time format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, time-format

I have user input field that accepts time value. Here is example of that value: `03:45:15.0` I would like to format this value with JavaScript to format the time like this: `03:35:15 PM`. Is there a way to complete this with Vanilla JS?

Thank you.

Comment: Why? its repeating logic. it already has 03: indicating before 12pm. in any case, you can do time = time + (Number(time.substring(0,2)) < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm')

Comment: Are you using `input type="time"`? If so, that time likely represents AM, not PM, since that input type returns values in 24 hour time.

Comment: @SteveTomlin Ok, what if I want in 24 hour format? Or if I want date plus time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you display JavaScript datetime in 12 hour AM/PM format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format)

Comment: Pick one - don't change the question mid-stream.

Comment: If you decide you want dates, then it's [How to format a JavaScript date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552461/215552). There are basically already questions and answers for formatting dates and times for every format under the sun.