# how to covert time hhmm format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

here i am getting a time value as `1700`. I want to convert this into a format like this `5pm`. I tried to do this with `moment` package. It has a lot of options, I'm not able to find the relevant format to achieve the output I am looking for.

Result has to be something like this:

1700 -> 5pm

0900 -> 9am

Current impl of mine is

```
moment("1500", "hh").format('LT') => 3:00 PM
```

Here the output is different, it has to be like 3pm.

Is there any way I can achieve this. Help me with your suggestions and feedback

Comment: already the same post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format

Comment: nope that is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use momentjs; if you are sure your input time will always be a 4-digit string, you can make your own simple formatting function (the following code is just the base concept, you might want to refine it a bit to better fit your needs):

```js
function formatTime(str) {
  const [hh, mm] = str.match(/[0-9]{2}/g);
  const hours = parseInt(hh);
  const ampm = hours < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm';
  
  return `${hours === 12 ? hours : hours % 12}${parseInt(mm) > 0 ? `:${mm}` : ''}${ampm}`
}

// test
['1500', '0900', '1345', '0000', '1217', '1805'].forEach(item => console.log(formatTime(item)));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `moment().format("hA");` does what you need. See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: this is the output i am getting

Comment: You should specify the input format in the moment() function, for example:
``moment('1500', 'hh').format("hA");
"3PM"``