# Is there any way to display time format with am/pm in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

time :
`{ $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M:%S:%L%z", date: "$generated_on", timezone: "+05:30" }}`
with the help of this time is generated but I want time in AM/PM format}\

Comment: if you are using it inside the pipeline, I guess, you need to add a custom js function but I think the better option would be to store the correct format in the first place

Answer (score 0):

So basically, for time being (version 5), [Mongo DB does not support](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#format-specifiers) the AM/PM format on the date object, you have two options:

**option one**: Store the correct format in the first place

**option two(heavy operation)**: store a JS function inside the MongoDB for this custom format and call that in your aggregation pipeline, [js function would be like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format):

```js
   function formatAMPM(date) {
      var hours = date.getHours();
      var minutes = date.getMinutes();
      var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
      hours = hours % 12;
      hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
      var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
      return strTime;
    }
```

Add MongoDB custom JS function `myCustomDate`:

```
 db.system.js.insertOne(
    {
        _id: "myCustomDate",
        value: function (date) {
            var hours = date.getHours();
            var minutes = date.getMinutes();
            var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
            hours = hours % 12;
            hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
            minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
            var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
            return strTime;
        }
    }
);
```

and use this based on your requirements [on `mapReduce` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/)