# How to separate date, time and day with title in react native code?

Tags: javascript, react-native

My API Date and Time Format is like this: [image]

I'm currently using this method to render the date and time in my code.
[image]

```
let d = new Date(item.starts_on);
let date = `${d.getMonth() + 1}/${d.getDate()}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
let time = `${d.getHours()}:${d.getMinutes()}`;
```

But i want to render it in this format [image] Pls do help me out

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment check that package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approach for doing it, first way (that is easier) using packages like [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) or [dayjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs) by using it you are be able to handle date and convert to many different shapes (for more information check the documents of them). For example if you want to separate **date** and **time** from a timestamp you can do it by **moment** like below:

```js
/*
  other your imports and codes
*/
let timestamp = moment(item.starts_on);
let date = timestamp.format('L');
let time = timestamp.format('LT');
/*
  other your codes
*/
```

Second way is using at instance of **Date**, for doing it you can:

```js
/*
  other your imports and codes
*/
let d = new Date(item.starts_on);
let date = `${d.getMonth() + 1}/${d.getDate()}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
let time = `${d.getHours()}:${d.getMinutes()}`;
/*
  other your codes
*/
```

***Update Answer***
For converting date to like "Sat 19 Mar 2022" you want, followings below:

```js
//fill in Months array
const Months = ["Jan", "Feb", ..., "Dec"];
//fill in Days of week array
const Days = ["Sun", "Mon", ..., "Sat"];
/*
  other your codes
*/
let d = new Date(item.starts_on);
let monthIndex = d.getMonth();
let month = Months[monthIndex];
let dayIndex = d.getDay();
let day = Days[dayIndex];

let date = `${day} ${d.getDate()} ${month} ${d.getFullYear()}`;
/*
  other your codes
*/
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I'm using the second way if i want it with the title like "19 March 2022" and the day "Saturday", how would the format look like?

Comment: In order to use name of the month in the second way, you must to define an array of the months of year then by **getMonth()** (no need more to plus it with one) , get index of the month and select related month by the array of months, so final date shape easily reaching out by a normal concatenation of day, month and year. For adding day of week to your date like the previous approach must to define an array for **days of the week** then by **getDay()** method get day and by it and the days array select that.

Comment: Can i have a sample structure of code like the above answer given https://stackoverflow.com/a/72739400/19185042

Comment: I will update the answer, you just need to update your question so as not to create ambiguity.

Comment: Done updating the question

Comment: @veshsilvan I update the answer but it was been good if you hadn't clear the previous question and just update question by ***Update*** topic.

Comment: thank you for the update. i have another question if i would like to have have "pm' and "am" in my time format...how would the format look like?

Comment: Your welcome, see link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format

Comment: Can i have sample tag code like the above solution "Update Answer"