# Converting JSON data 24 hour time to 12 hour with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

The JSON I'm pulling returns the time and date information together in this format:

```
06-16-2013 16:00:00
```

What I need to do is convert it from 24 hour time to 12 hour time (with AM and PM, preferably). I've seen similar posts and functions on here, but none that seem to work with this particular formatting ([here is one good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898574/converting-24-hour-time-to-12-hour-time-w-am-pm-using-javascript)).

My JavaScript isn't superb, which might be part of the problem when it comes to getting other functions to work for me.

Comment: think about a javascript date-time library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Note: JavaScript only officially supports a simplified [ISO 8601 Extended Format](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15): `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`. Other formats can be supported by an individual JavaScript engine, but the exact list of formats varies from one engine to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `momentjs` to format the date in the way you prefer. First include momentjs http://momentjs.com/ in your project, and then you will be able to do:

```
moment('06-16-2013 16:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS').format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss a')
```

Comment: Note that the capital "MM" is for Months not Minutes.