# Converting specific military time with Angular and Javascript filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I see that I various times like

```
01:45
//and
15:00
```

I assume that date is HH:MM   in military ?

While have I seen some advanced functions then parse sentences and even some using the seconds like HH:MM:SS  ,  I am wanting a simple and accurate way of getting the HH:MM

So I assume 15:00 is 3:00 ?

This function below is not going to work because I already have ":" 
so below assumed HHMM  right?  when I believe I need HH:MM to be parsed ?

```
var getTravelTimeFormatted = function (str) {
    var hours = Math.trunc(str / 60),
        minutes = str % 60;
        return hours + ':' + minutes;
    };
```

**Update**

Ok, I assume that 15:00 is 3:00 , right?

So i stripped out the incoming ":" and then add it back 
problem is the result is  `25.0`   so what does that mean?

```
var getTravelTimeFormatted = function (str) {
    str = str.replace(/:/g,'');
    var hours = Math.trunc(str / 60),
    minutes = str % 60;
    return hours + ':' + minutes;
};

console.log(getTravelTimeFormatted('15:00'));
```

Comment: Or the 24-hour clock.

Comment: oh, fun ..:/     that function I posted even if i use that and pass in 1500 , i end up with 25:0     ughhh  not what I want

Comment: Are you trying to convert a 24-Hour format into a 12-Hour format?

Comment: I think that is what I need to do.

Comment: So you have a string "15:00" that you want to convert into a 12-Hour format time?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: you need to add two integers: am and pm to know what the 12 hour cycles of the 24 cycles should represent.. when you can check for which of those cycles you need, you can pinpoint your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a string HH:MM you can just split then subtract 12 hours. Here's a naive solution that doesn't check for invalid input.

```
function TwelveHourFormat(time) {
    var dtParts = time.split(":");

    var hours = dtParts[0];
    var minutes = dtParts[1];
    var suffix = "AM";

    if (hours > 12) {
        hours = hours - 12;
        suffix = "PM";
    }
    else if (hours == "00") {
        hours = 12;
        suffix = "AM";
    }
    else if (hours == "12") {
        suffix = "PM";
    }

    return (hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix);
}
```

Comment: I was playing with one I found that was passing in a date... with month day year and time  and trying to get rid of the m/d/y  was a pain,  yours works great  thx !

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [*Converting 24 hour time to 12 hour time w/ AM & PM using Javascript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898574/converting-24-hour-time-to-12-hour-time-w-am-pm-using-javascript). Jasen's answer is fine, and more concise than the duplicate, but the function can be a little more concise:

```js
/* Convert time in 24 hour hh:mm format to 12 hour h:mm ap format
** @param {string} time - in hh:mm format (e.g. 14:30)
** @returns {string} time in 12 hour format (e.g. 2:30 PM)
*/
function to12HourTime(time) {
  var b = time.split(/\D/);
  return (b[0]%12 || 12) + ':' + b[1] +
         (b[0]<11? ' AM' : ' PM');
}

// Some tests
['23:15','2:15','03:15','00:30'].forEach(function(v) {
    console.log(v + ' => ' + to12HourTime(v));
});
```