# how could i access setter and getter on javascript object?

Tags: javascript, oop

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>latihan 2 Objek</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         function timeObjc(hour,minute,second){
                this.hour= hour;
                this.minute = minute;
                this.second= second;       
                this.setTime= function(whathour,whatminute,whatscnd){
                                    this.hour=whathour;
                                    this.minute =whatminute;
                                    this.second =whatscnd;
                                };
                this.runTime = function(){return this.hour+":"+this.minute+":"+this.second};
            }
            timeObjc.setTime(10,22,36);
            timeObjc.runTime();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

i want to set the time manually outside the function and print it with the runTime functio, but it keep error that said "setTime is not a function"..
i would be grateful to know wht i'm missing and why is it happening.
thanks in advance

Comment: You need to create a new timeObjc and assign the object to a variable. var newTimeObjc = new timeObjc(); newTimeObjc.setTime(10,22,36);

Comment: you try to use static construction without using its syntax. Your syntax is a constructor function, you need then to instantiate it. To use a static context, you have to add the memeber functions outside of the "class" function, using its name (which is a bit strange)

Comment: @Kaddath thanks it fixed, but how if i want to make multiple time model (24 and 12) through the argument of run time function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't initialized your `timeObjc` yet. And you're trying to run `setTime` as a static method, which it's not.

You have to first initialize the object, then run its `setTime` function.

```
function timeObjc(hour,minute,second){
    this.hour= hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.second= second;       
    this.setTime= function(whathour,whatminute,whatscnd){
                        this.hour=whathour;
                        this.minute =whatminute;
                        this.second =whatscnd;
                    };
    this.runTime = function(){return this.hour+":"+this.minute+":"+this.second};
}
var obj = timeObj(1,1,1)
obj.setTime(10,22,36);
obj.runTime();
```

Comment: thanks it fixed, but how if i want to make multiple time model (24 and 12) through the argument of run time function?

Comment: You could add a parameter to the `runTime` function. `this.runTime = function(format) { format = format || 24; if (format === 24) { ... } else { ... } }` Does that make sense?

Comment: it should be changing the hour format between 12 and 24 hour depend on which we choosing.. e.g if i want print 12:20:33 in 24 hour format  and i call the runtime function and the paramater is 24, it should be automatically changing the hour to be 00:20:33.. any idea?

Comment: Check out this stackoverflow for a sure fire way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898574/converting-24-hour-time-to-12-hour-time-w-am-pm-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Create new object using `new` keyword.

like `var timeObject = new timeObjc(11, 22, 33)`
then `timeObjc.setTime(2,3,4)`