# How to map array of numbers to timing values

Tags: javascript

Hi I have an array of numbers

```
let timearray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23];
```

But the problem is I am displaying the array value in DOM, but I want it such a way that the values been mapped accordingly. Ex: If 0 -> 12:00am, if its 18 -> 6:00pm. How can I do that? Any idea guys? I can only think of map using if else. But that seems pretty ugly. Any idea guys?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to turn 24 hour time into 12 hour time?

Comment: It seems he wants to convert integers into a raw hour.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your array like this:

```js
const timearray = [
 '12:00am',
 '01:00am',
 '02:00am',
 '03:00am',
...
 '10:00pm',
 '11:00pm',
]
```

```js
console.log(timearray[3])
// 03:00am
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't unfortunately. The specific time value is coming from a  range slider. range from 0 to 23. So I can't give the slider string values

Comment: So I have a logic in my JSX like this -> ```{value}{":00"}<span>{value > 12 ? 'pm' :'am'}</span> ```

Comment: So the "am" and "pm" is sort of dynamic. But when the value reaches 13, I need to convert to 1:00pm etc.

Comment: This might look dumb but actually is the most efficient way to do it lol

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function you can use (and improve based on your needs):

```js
const timeArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23];
const result = timeArray.map(t => {
  const ampm = t % 12;
  return `${ampm === 0 ? 12 : ampm}:00${t >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am'}`;
});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is for:

```
let timearray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]

let mapped = timearray.map(function(value) {
    switch (value) {
        case 0: return "12:00am"
        // ..
        case 18: return "6:00pm"
    }
})
```

Or you can use an object

```
let timearray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]

let map = {
    0: "12:00am",
    18: "6:00pm"
}

let mapped = timearray.map(function(value) {
    return map[value]
})
```

If you simply want to convert 24 hour time to 12 hour time **AND NOT MAP THE VALUES** then google for `"24 hour time to 12 hour time"` and you'll find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To convert integers to hours in 12-hour format with am/pm format you can use:

```js
let timearray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23];

timearray.forEach(x => {
  var suffix = x >= 12 ? "pm":"am"; 
  hours = ((x + 11) % 12 + 1) + suffix;
  console.log(hours);
  }
);
```

Based on code from this answer: [Converting 24 hour time to 12 hour time w/ AM & PM using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14399178/2314737)

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider leveraging a library such as, moment.js (https://momentjs.com/) in this situation.
Here is an example of usage in your case:

```
var time = moment(2,"h:hh A");
console.log(time);
// 02:00am
```

The benefit from this approach is that you would be able to easily format the output, if required to.